# VNC error - only supporting 8, 15, 16 and 24 bpp rdp connections

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

From an Ubuntu 16.04 system, I am trying to make a remote desktop connection using `Remmina Remote Desktop Client` version 1.1.2 to a fedora server. I can login, but I get the message

> VNC error - only supporting 8, 15, 16 and 24 bpp rdp connections

Then I am logged out. This seems to be a client based system, because I can login from a Windows system. How can I change the bpp for the client? Do I have to change the bpp for my client system?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for your `Remmina Remote Desktop Client`, there should be an option to adjust the "color depth", change that to a supported `bpp` (bits per pixel) setting and see if that works.

Comment: There is no such option. I find it only for resolution.

Comment: According to the [screenshots in the Remmina User's Guide](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Remmina-User%27s-guide), there is an option in the profile to adjust the color depth.